# re-open after close streamController/ Rx?

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I need to close my `streamController/BehaviorSubject` and then I need to re-start it? how do I do it?

```
static StreamSubscription stream;

<List<BookModel>> _controller = StreamController<List<BookModel>>.broadcast();
        
// BehaviorSubject<List<BookModel>> _controller = BehaviorSubject<List<BookModel>>();
    
    
    //try to close
    
void close() {
    stream?.cancel();
    _controller.close();
}
    
    
    //try to re-open

void reOpen(){
  _controller = BehaviorSubject<List<BookModel>>();
}
```

Comment: are you sure you dont want to use `StreamSubscription.pause` / `resume`? `pause` docs say: *"Request that the stream pauses events until further notice.

While paused, the subscription will not fire any events. If it receives events from its source, they will be buffered until the subscription is resumed. For non-broadcast streams, the underlying source is usually informed about the pause, so it can stop generating events until the subscription is resumed."*

Comment: @pskink is I use `pause` no need to close streamController?

Answer (score 0):

Using this way.

```
void reOpen() {
   _controller = StreamController<List<BookModel>>.broadcast();
}
```